# appengine sms verification: multiple accounts?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a workaround to SMS verifying multiple app engine accounts with the same mobile number?  I have an Apps account and a congruent Google account and I use them interchangeably to administer my apps (some on my domain, some on Google apps) and separately for different email roles.  Unfortunately, I cannot verify my Google account because I already used my mobile number for my apps account verification?

Any workarounds?  Any Google engineers out there that want to rethink the SMS verification process, and at least allow a few accounts to verify with the same mobile number?

Answer (score 6):

Just send them a message via the [SMS issues form](https://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues) which is linked from the [SMS FAQ](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/sms.html).

I have three google accounts - a personal one, a business one, and an apps one, but only one mobile number. I used my mobile to verify the personal account, and then requested permission for the other two. They responded quickly both times (within about a day).